# Pivoting numpy array about an element in my array

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I need to be able to pivot my numpy array about a certain element in my array.

Say I have the array `x = [a b c d e f g]`.

I know the operation to reverse it: `x_arr = [::-1] == [g f e d c b a]`

But let's say I want to pivot my original array about `c`, then I want: `[e d c b a 0 0]`

I'm thinking reversing then some sort of concatenating and reduction, but some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following script where `a` is the array, `p` is the index of the pivot element, and `f` is used to pad the array after the pivot.  The indices for truncating the arrays were found with some logic and trial and error.  Note that in the case of an even length array, the center index `c` will be `x.5` where `x` is an integer, while for an odd length array it will be `x.0`.  This allows the if statements to correctly handle both even and odd length arrays.

In the first case, when the pivot element is the center of the array, I simply return the reverse of the array.  Note that an even length array will never execute this if statement.

In the second case, when the pivot element is before the center of the array, I remove the elements from the reversed array that would fall outside of the pivotted array.  Then I return this shortened array right padded with `f` to the length of `a`.

The only difference between the third case, where the pivot element is after the center of the array, and the second case is that the shortened array is left padded instead of right padded.

Finally, if none of the if statements execute due to some unforeseen error, I return `None`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

def pivot(a,p,f):
    la = len(a)
    c = la/2.0-0.5
    x = a[::-1]
    if p==c:
        return x
    if p<c:
        x = x[la-(2*p+1):]        
        lpad = la-len(x)
        pad = np.repeat(f,lpad)
        return np.append(x,pad)
    if p>c:
        x = x[:2*(la-p)-1]
        lpad = la-len(x)
        pad = np.repeat(f,lpad)
        return np.append(pad,x)
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used numpy, so i am not much familiar with that, 
But what you want to achieve is pretty simple

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
pivot = 'c'

len_x = len(x)
pad_len = len_x - len(x[:x.index(pivot)*2 + 1])

y = x[:x.index(pivot)*2 + 1]
y = list(reversed(y))

for i in range(pad_len):
    y.append('0')

print y
```

Output is `['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', '0', '0']`

I hope this is what you where looking for.

Comment: What about if the elements in x are floats and I need to pivot around an integer value?

Comment: This does not work correctly for pivot elements that are to the right of the center of the array.  I assume the OP wanted that functionality as well.